# C# WinForms Thread Manager

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I want to build a Thread Manager in my `C# WinForms` application.

This is how I add new Thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delay));

    //MY CODE

    RemoveCurrentThread();
});
threadArr.Add(thread);
thread.Start();
```

This is how I remove the Thread:

```
public void RemoveCurrentThread()
{
    if (threadArr.Contains(Thread.CurrentThread))
    {
        threadArr.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread);
    }
}
```

And there are sometimes that I want to cancel all the running thread so I use:

```
public void CancelAllThreads()
{
    if (threadArr.Count == 0)
        return;

    foreach (Thread item in threadArr)
    {
        if (item.IsAlive)
            item.Abort();
    }

    threadArr.Clear();
}
```

The issue with this code is that all the Thread are created and then start waiting for the delay to finish(I have a lot of Threads in the application and I'm afraid it's take a lot of the CPU from the computer).
There is any built-in code to start a Thread after a delay of a couple of seconds?

Thanks!

Comment: Thread.Sleep() doesn’t use any CPU don’t worry.

Comment: Please never ever call `Thread.Abort()` unless you are trying to crash out of your app. It can leave the run-time in a corrupted state and you just can't trust your code to run properly afterwards.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you hoping that the threads will do for you? Can you tell us what your app is trying to do?

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks! so what is your suggestion to cancel a running Thread?

Comment: @MTA - You cannot cancel a running thread. You can only co-operatively notify the thread to allow it to end naturally.